# What does Tensorflow mean with 'positive_threshold_0.500000_mean'?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Tensorflow's [evaluate function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#evaluate) spits out a bunch of stats:

```
accuracy: 0.915224
accuracy/baseline_target_mean: 0.220896
accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.915224
auc: 0.937926
global_step: 200
labels/actual_target_mean: 0.220896
labels/prediction_mean: 0.203677
loss: 0.247065
precision/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.991379
recall/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.621622
```

What do `baseline_target_mean` (after accuracy) and `positive_threshold_0.500000_mean` (after recall and precision) mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you get these statistics, I assume you are doing a binary classification.

`baseline_target_mean` is the mean of the class labels in your data, i.e. in this example, assuming you have class labels 0 and 1, about 22% of your test examples belong to class 1, the remaining examples belong to class 0. Class labels can be arbitrary numbers, so the interpretation depends on your data, what I described is just one possibility because I don't know the data you are using.

`positive_threshold_0.500000_mean` just means that examples for which the prediction is above the threshold of 0.5 are considered positive examples whereas those below 0.5 are negative